# Subreport in CrystalReport

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, ado.net, crystal-reports, subreport

Here is my report: 
https://sites.google.com/site/bullxtech/MarchDang_Fiche.rpt?attredirects=0&d=1

I added to an existing report, the last part that start from "SGH/CLP".

I'm not Expert on CrystalReport, but i think i did exactly the same as previous subreport, but my subreports do not get data: thay don't execute the stored procedure.

NB:the suppression is conditional, in my case all the sections are included

any help?
best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your subreport isn't getting data, you need to check your datasource.  You should be able to run your subreport as if it was a main report.  If you do that and don't see values, you know the problem is with the datasource connection.

If there's data when you run the subreport but not within the report, then check the subreport's links within the main report.